# Binding a WPF Button CommandParameter to the Button itself in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate, commandparameter

I have a DataTemplate that represents AppBar buttons that I declare through a collection of custom AppBarCommand objects.

```
  public AppBarCommand(RelayCommand command, string buttonstyle)
  {
     Command = command;
     ButtonStyle = buttonstyle;
  }

<DataTemplate>
   <Button Command="{Binding Command}"
           Style="{Binding ButtonStyle, Converter={StaticResource StringNameToStyleConverter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I would like to add a CommandParameter binding, but the parameter has to be the Button itself. This is so I can set the PlacementTarget of a Callisto flyout. Is this possible?

Comment: Probably easier to handle the Button's Click event. The first argument you receive in your handler will be the Button.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
<Button Command="{Binding Command}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Your Command property should be the generic version of the `RelayCommand`: `RelayCommand<object>` for instance.

Answer (score 6):

Answer like Miklós Balogh said, or you can:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter={Binding ElementName=MyButton ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I used it in a bit different context:

```
<MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={ RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={ x:Type Window}}, Path= DataContext.MyListItemCommand}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

so I assume that even if you write it like this

```
<Button Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

it should work.

I also recommend reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488014/are-binding-path-and-binding-really-equal) to understand it better.