# How to get HyperLink Text from C# in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF `Hyperlink` which I'm trying to get the text content from.

For example:

```
<Hyperlink Command="{Binding CustomersCommand}" Name="HLCustomers">
    Customers
</Hyperlink>
```

This is not possible using the usual manner of accessing a `Text` property or using `VisualTreeHelper` to get some child text element, since `Hyperlink` is not a visual element. I tried to get the text from `FirstInline` but this also doesn't give me the text.

How would I get the value "Customers" from the `Hyperlink` element in the above example at runtime?

Comment: Does using CommandParameter="Customers" work for you? Or bind to the control. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413985/binding-a-wpf-button-commandparameter-to-the-button-itself-in-datatemplate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really need to get the text contained within the `Hyperlink`, you can dig in to the [`Inlines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.span.inlines.aspx) property it exposes and get it.

```
var run = HLCustomers.Inlines.FirstOrDefault() as Run;
string text = run == null ? string.Empty : run.Text;
```

Note, that this will only work if the first inline in your `Hyperlink` is indeed a `Run`. You can finagle with this example for more complex cases.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a `TextBlock` inside and enjoy its binding flexibility .

If it's still not an option for you - use `Run.Text` property which is perfectly suitable solution for `Hyperlink`

Comment: But is the same, How to get the text?

Answer (score 1):

Is adding a text block a problem?

```
<Hyperlink Command="{Binding CustomersCommand}" Name="HLCustomers">
    <TextBlock Name="HLCustomersContent">
        Customers
    </TextBlock>
</Hyperlink>
```

Then you could just reference it as:

```
var text = HLCustomersContent.Text;
```

The `.Text` property on a WPF Hyperlink object is set to internal, so unless you overrode it and exposed the text property, it is not as easily as accessible as you would might like.