# Get the text from clicked Hyperlink

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, hyperlink

I created some Hyperlinks using the code below:

```
 public Class_List()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    StackPanel myStackPanel = new StackPanel();
    TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
    txt.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
    txt.FontFamily = new FontFamily("03SmartFontUI");
    txt.FontSize = 25;
    txt.Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 5);
    Run run = new Run(className);
    Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink(run);                                    
    link.Click += Link_Click;                                               
    txt.Inlines.Add(link);
}
```

Now, I want to get the text of the hyperlink and store it on string s:

```
private void Link_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string s = (sender as Hyperlink).Inlines.ToString();

    Class_Page class_page = new Class_Page();
    NavigationService.Navigate(class_page);
}
```

However instead of the hyperlink text, I got

> System.Windows.Documents.InlineCollection

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645110/how-to-get-hyperlink-text-from-c-sharp-in-wpf

Comment: @Filburt sorry, I forgot to copy another line. Code edited above.

Comment: `((sender as Hyperlink).Inlines.FirstInline as Run).Text` or whatever the Hyperlink's first inline is.

Comment: @Meloviz Thank you very much, that worked!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that type because you are actually accessing the entire collection of `Inline`s rather than the `Inline` you're looking for. The fastest way to access the `Run`'s text you're using as the first `Inline` in the `Hyperlink`'s `InlineCollection` is to do this:

```
((sender as Hyperlink).Inlines.FirstInline as Run).Text;
```