# Accessing a Button's data context on click

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a typical game grid - a UniformGrid consisting of Buttons. The buttons are each data-bound to individual "Cell" objects. Is there a way to access the button itself (and by extension, the particular object that the button is bound to) in the Button's click handler?

Comment: I think this is what you're asking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413985/binding-a-wpf-button-commandparameter-to-the-button-itself-in-datatemplate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each button handles its own click event then you can use `sender` that is passed to event handler:

```
var button = sender as Button;
```

or if you have one `Button.Click` handler for all buttons on `UniformGrid` for example

```
var button = e.OriginalSource as Button;
```

and then getting `DataContext` is as easy as:

```
var context = button.DataContext;
```